# Select a DISTINCT ID, then pull data from another table

Tags: mysql, logic

I have 2 MySQL tables, one for parts, and one for years. I can't figure out how to make a table on stackoverflow.. keeps making headers so here's my weak attempt to explain what I need.

Table 1

```
id | part_id | years
====================
 0 |    15   | 1945
 1 |    15   | 1946
 2 |    16   | 1944
 3 |    16   | 1947
 4 |    16   | 1948
 5 |    17   | 1953
```

As you may have guessed, part_id is the id number of the part in the parts table. Now, I know I have this to pull out a distinct part id, based on the year. That part is easy.

```
SELECT DISTINCT part_id FROM `years` WHERE year BETWEEN 1945 AND 1949
```

This is just an example, but that works exactly like I want it to. Gives me

15 and 16. Just one time. Which is great.

Now, do I need to do a loop in php to get the information from parts? I'm not sure how to do a join here.

```
<?php
foreach($item_pulled_from_db as $newid) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'parts' WHERE id = $newid";
} // I know there's more stuff to do in here, just a basic overview for you to look at
?>
```

Should I do the above code? Is there a way to select a DISTINCT part_id and then pull the data from another table for that ID in MySQL? Or do I have to do a loop like this?

Edit: I hope this isn't too confusing of a question. I'm not very good with words, which is why I like to program. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a join:

```
SELECT parts.*
FROM parts
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT part_id
      FROM years
      WHERE year BETWEEN 1945 AND 1949) years
ON parts.id = years.part_id
```

Comment: THIS worked perfectly for me. Thanks. I'm still getting used to these joins. And when I throw in new things like DISTINCT (new for me at least) joins start to look kinda scary. Even though I know it's easy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull this off using a JOIN in a single query.  Try:

```
SELECT `parts`.* FROM `parts`
INNER JOIN `years` ON `years`.`part_id` = `parts`.`id`
WHERE `years`.`year` BETWEEN 1945 AND 1949
```

Execute that single query from PHP and then fetch the result set.  It should be the same as what you would get using the multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

This query give you the result you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.*
FROM 
    years y
INNER JOIN
    parts p ON p.id = y.part_id
WHERE 
    y.year BETWEEN 1945 AND 1949
```

Comment: This pulls out what I need, BUT it duplicates information. It pulls each part more than once. I just need to find if a part is between those two numbers, if it is, pull it out once and don't bother with it again.

Comment: Add the `DISTINCT` option to remove duplicates as I did above.